# Caching in Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat

How do I enable caching in Tomcat server so static files can be served from cache for browsers.

I tried with web.xml changes but not sure what code needs to be put in.

Can someone please help on same.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are steps to implement Caching  on Tomcat server

1. You will have to download "Cache Filter" jar file from the below location.
   http://code.google.com/p/cache-filter/downloads/list
2. Put that jar file in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib location.
3. Edit tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml file and add filter and filter-mapping properties as mentioned below.

   ```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>static</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
   <param-value>2592000</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter>
   <filter-name>cssCache</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
   <param-value>604800</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter>
   <filter-name>jsCache</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>private</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
   <param-value>216000</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>cssCache</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>jsCache</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
4. Restart Tomcat and check the expires headers on browsers.

Reference: http://www.knowarth.com/blog/-/blogs/caching-tomcat-server